# Jenkins build randomly fails with a StackOverflowError during AspectJ weaving

Tags: build, maven-2, jenkins, aspectj

Our Jenkins (maven) build randomly fails with the following error stack:

```
 -- (StackOverflowError) null
null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:273)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:209)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.UnresolvedType.resolve(UnresolvedType.java:645)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getRawType(ResolvedType.java:2331)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:427)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:393)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:427)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:393)
```

this failure is definitely not caused by actual code change as usually after such a failure, the subsequent build, manually triggered (i.e. not code committed), succeeds.

Versions are as follows :

Jenkins: 1.501

maven: 2.2.2

aspectjrt: 1.6.10

Anyone has an idea how to address this?

Comment: Although this build failure happens randomly it always happens at the end of weaving the same class. I can't figure out what wrong with that class though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason upgrading to the latest version of aspectj didn't fix the issue was because aspectj maven plugin version 1.3 was defined in the pom. This version of the plugin has a dependency on aspectj version 1.6.7 (version prior to 1.6.8 where fix was introduced). Upgrading the plugin to version 1.4 (which depends on aspectj version 1.6.11) seems to have fixed the problem as we didn't get the StackOverflowError exception since then.

In general terms, dependency tree (including plugins) should be checked in case there is an obsolete hidden dependency.

The commands to find out the dependency tree (including plugins) are :

`mvn dependency:tree`

and

`mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but a similar error occurred due to a bug which was fixed in 1.6.8. What blocks you from upgrading to the current AspectJ release? Yours is really old.

Comment: that's what I read in some other forums, I thought any version subsequent to 1.6.8 would do. We are at a stage of the project where we'd rather not take the risk to upgrade this dependency. That said, I will try the most recent version to see if that fixes the problem

Comment: Upgrading to latest version of aspectjrt (1.7.2) didn't help